# How to export a Hbase table using Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I want to export a Hbase table to HDFS filesystem using Java.
I tried using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.createSubmittableJob()` method to create a Hbase Job.
I passed 2 arguments, 1-Hbase configuration, 2-String array with Table name and backup.

But, when I run the code I am getting some weird exception like this

Caused by:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack|Exception Details:|  Location:|    org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/Export.getExportFilter([Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter; @56: invokespecial|  Reason:|    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable'|  Current Frame:|    bci: @56|    flags: { }|    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String' }|    stack: { uninitialized 41, uninitialized 41, 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/CompareFilter$CompareOp', 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator' }|  Bytecode:|    0000000: 014c 2abe 08a4 0009 2a08 32a7 0004 014d|    0000010: 2cc7 0005 01b0 2c12 34b6 0035 9900 232c|    0000020: 042c b600 36b6 0037 4ebb 0038 59b2 0039|    0000030: bb00 3a59 2db7 003b b700 3c4c a700 0fbb|    0000040: 003d 592c b800 26b7 003e 4c2b b0       |  Stackmap Table:|    append_frame(@14,Object[#133])|    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@15,Object[#138])|    append_frame(@22,Object[#138])|    same_frame(@63)|    same_frame(@75)|
    at com.sample.client.takeBackup(HdfsClient.java:428)
    at com.sample.client.backupData(BackupRestoreService.java:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ServletContainerBridge.service(ServletContainerBridge.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have passed longer array as args, otherwise there would be no such exception. Post entire code.

```
private static Filter getExportFilter(String[] args) {
Filter exportFilter = null;
String filterCriteria = (args.length > 5) ? args[5]: null;
if (filterCriteria == null) return null;
if (filterCriteria.startsWith("^")) {
  String regexPattern = filterCriteria.substring(1, filterCriteria.length());
  exportFilter = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator(regexPattern));
} else {
  exportFilter = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytesBinary(filterCriteria));
}
return exportFilter;
}
```